# how to start my app, automatically, everytime the phone is switched on?

Tags: android

My application requires to be started everytime the phone is switched off and switched on i.e it should start running automatically like an anti-virus software on start up. Is it possible??? I am totally clueless!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I remeber right, there is a system broadcast intent, when the system has booted...

maybe you can catch it and fire up an intent to your app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android